# Как вывести элементы структуры в Си?

Tags: c++, c

**как вывести элементы структуры в Си** ,в C++ с помощью cout всё работает, в Си с printf что-то не получается, может мой синтаксис не верен.

**Вот часть кода, с cout с++, оно работает.**

```
struct game
    {
        char title[100];
        char players[100];
        char platform[100];
        char genre[100];
        char developer[100];
        int year;
        unsigned int min_cpu;
        unsigned int min_ram;
        unsigned int min_hdd;
    
    
        void getInfo()
        {  
          cout << " title: " << title << endl;
            cout << " players: " << players << endl;
             cout << " platform:" <<  platform << endl;
              cout << " genre: " << genre << endl;
               cout << " developer: " << developer << endl;
                cout << " year: " << year << endl;
                 cout << " min_cpu: " << min_cpu << endl;
                  cout << " min_ram: " << min_ram << endl;
                   cout << " min_hdd: " << min_hdd << endl;
```

Comment: Вы показали код, который работает, а код который не работает решили не показывать. Интересный подход.

Comment: В си нет методов, есть функции, передавайте указатель на структуру в функцию, и обрабатывайте данные через указатель.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно пишите форматную строку, и пребудет с вами корректный вывод...

```
cout << " title: " << title << endl;
printf("%s\n",title);

cout << " year: " << year << endl;
printf("%d\n",year);

cout << " min_cpu: " << min_cpu << endl;
printf("%u\n",min_cpu);
```